# How to print Instaloader data to CSV?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, instaloader

I'm not sure the root of this problem - ultimately, I'm trying to retrieve the followers of an Instagram account ("strengthinsheets") and their number of followers.

There are no issues with the data -- however, I originally tried to use Gspread and send it right to a Google Sheet.  This seemed to time out regularly.

Now, I'm just trying to print the info to a CSV -- the below script will give me the correct results (not in a CSV):

```
import csv
from turtle import pd
import instaloader

headers = {

    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

loader = instaloader.Instaloader()

loader.login("username", "password!")

profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(loader.context, "strengthinsheets")

followees = profile.get_followees()

for followee in profile.get_followees():
    print((followee.full_name, followee.username, followee.followees))
```

However, in order to make this work daily, I'm thinking it would be best to just save all the data to a CSV.  I tried altering in this way:

```
import csv
from turtle import pd
import instaloader

headers = {

    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

loader = instaloader.Instaloader()

loader.login("username", "password!")

profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(loader.context, "strengthinsheets")

followees = profile.get_followees()

for followee in profile.get_followees():
    (followee.full_name, followee.username, followee.followees)

with open('followers.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(followee)
```

I'm not 100% positive I extracted to a CSV correctly, I based my code off documentation I found online, but it was confusing (I previously did it with .to_csv when pulling dataframes, but couldn't get that working this way).. I'm new to this, but would really love a file like this - it seems very attainable but if I'm wrong would love to hear it from an expert.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your problem ...

... but I would write it inside `for`-loop using `writerow()` (without char `s` at the end).

```
with open('followers.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow("full_name", "username", "followees")  # header
    for followee in profile.get_followees():
        writer.writerow( (followee.full_name, followee.username, followee.followees) )
```

Or first I would create list with all rows and later use `writerows()` (with `s` at the end)

```
all_followees = []

for followee in profile.get_followees():
    all_followees.append( (followee.full_name, followee.username, followee.followees) )
 
with open('followers.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow("full_name", "username", "followees")  # header
    writer.writerows( all_followees )
```

and the same with `DataFrame`

```
all_followees = []

for followee in profile.get_followees():
    all_followees.append( (followee.full_name, followee.username, followee.followees) )
 
df = pd.DataFrame(all_followees, columns=("full_name", "username", "followees"))

df.to_csv('followers.csv', index=False)
```